# Neither Raman nor IR Active vibrational modes of water

Tags: physical-chemistry

How can we find vibration modes of water that are not in IR and Raman spectroscopy? I thought these modes creat when a transition happens between 2 modes i.e from mode to another mode.

Comment: Do you have a *specific* example of a vibration which neither changes a dipole moment (then spotted in IR spectroscopy), nor the polarizability of the electron cloud (Raman)?  Of course, there are vibrations spot with both techniques, too.